# executeUpdate Delete All

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have a domain class called `ApplicantFile` and I want to delete all the rows within this table at certain times. The following is what I am trying:

```
ApplicantFile.executeUpdate('DELETE FROM APPLICANT_FILE')
```

and I get this error:

```
APPLICANT_FILE is not mapped [DELETE FROM APPLICANT_FILE]
```

Here is my domain class:

```
class ApplicantFile {

    String description
    String path

    static mapping = {
        table schema:"EIUISSVF", name:"APPLICANT_FILE"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `executeQuery` is a domain method, you don't need to point to the table in your database, you need to point to your domain, in this case `ApplicantFile`. And the `DELETE` function in SQL doesn't need the `*`.

Updating your statement:

```
ApplicantFile.executeUpdate("delete ApplicantFile")
```

For more examples:
[executeUpdate Grails](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.2.1/ref/Domain%20Classes/executeUpdate.html).